# How do I make Windows mute background applications?

Tags: windows-10, audio, gaming

I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> quite often to get out of a game to watch a video or something but the game sound still plays when the game is minimized. Is there any way to make Windows mute background applications but without stopping them (as it is an online game and I would loose connection I guess)?

If there is no option for that is it possible to create some kind of shortcut to mute/unmute a specific game?

Comment: Click on the sound icon in taskbar at very right. Then click Mixer, you'll see all the programs those are playing sound.

Comment: sure but I dont want to do this every trime manualy when I alt tab. I'm looking for something that does this automaticly.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason this feature seems impossible in Windows.  I've been researching on google, you and me seem to be some of the only people who want this feature.

HOWEVER I HAVE A SOLUTION FOR YOU!  On Steam (and likely elsewhere) there is a utility called Borderless Gaming.  Its main function is to allow running a fullscreen game as borderless windowed (for games that don't support this.)

However it also has an auxiliary function: "Mute In Background."  And it does exactly that.  You can add your games to its interface, and tell it not to mess with your window size.  Just mute when in background.  And it works.

Comment: For future readers, I think mercster is refering to https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming/releases. The latest .exe file worked for me; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python script that mutes a specific app when it's in the background and unmutes it when it's in the foreground.

```
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities
import win32gui
import win32process
import time

target_app_class = "CHANGE_THIS"

def find_process_id():
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(target_app_class, None)
    if hwnd != 0:
        _, process_id = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        return process_id
    return None

def app_is_in_foreground():
    try:
        act_name = win32gui.GetClassName(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    except win32gui.error:
        act_name = ""
    
    return act_name == target_app_class

def change_app_mute(process_id, mute=1):
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        if session.Process and session.Process.pid == process_id:
            session.SimpleAudioVolume.SetMute(mute, None)

while True:
    process_id = find_process_id()
    if process_id:
        if app_is_in_foreground():
            change_app_mute(process_id, 0)
        else:
            change_app_mute(process_id)
    time.sleep(1)
#   with open("log.txt", "a") as file:
#        file.write(win32gui.GetClassName(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) + "\n")
```

Remeber to `pip install pycaw pywin32` first.
Tested with Python 3.10.6 on Windows 11.

Replace CHANGE_THIS with the app's class name.
To find the name, uncomment the last 2 lines, run the script, put the app in the foreground and stop the script. You will find the name (among others apps) in log.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I created another tool which can do this:

https://github.com/TomiBelan/mute-on-focus-lost

> This script can automatically mute playing audio for an application
> when it loses focus, and unmute it when it regains focus. The feature
> is sometimes also known as "mute in background", "mute when inactive",
> "mute on minimize", or "mute on Alt+Tab".
>
> For example, this is useful for games if you need to Alt+Tab out of
> the game and watch a video, but the game sounds keep playing. Some
> games have a built in "mute on focus lost" option, but this script
> should work for apps and games that don't.
>
> Press **Win+F1** to mute/unmute the active app right now.
>
> Press **Win+F2** to enable "mute on focus lost" mode for the active
> app. A short beep will let you know it worked. In this mode, the app
> will mute when you minimize it or switch to another window, and unmute
> when you switch back. Pressing the key again will disable "mute on
> focus lost" mode for this app and play a lower beep.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a .Net tool to solve this issue. Here is a working version: https://github.com/nefares/Background-Muter.

It can automatically detect foreground windows via WinAPI, and mute any apps not in foreground. It also lets you define exceptions for applications never to be muted (such as a music player).

Let me know what you think. For issues/ feature suggestions feel free to use github issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I believe Windows doesn't support this feature out of the box.

Thankfully, there's an open source app which solves this problem.

It's called Background-Muter and the link is https://github.com/nefares/Background-Muter

Comment: Do not just repeat answers from a year ago and paste their solution as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

(Solution on windows)
here's a better solution and it works for probably everything and it's pretty simple
all you need to do is go to sound settings, scroll down until you see "advanced sound options" and "App volume and device preferences" and click "App volume and device preferences" from there you can change the volume of a certain game or software

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer this question because the question asks for a way to mute all running background processes while your answer tells how to mute a specific program.

Comment: This answer shouldn't have been downvoted, as it is quite useful even if it doesn't answer the question exactly. I was looking for a way to mute a specific app and it was at the top of Google search.