# Suddenly I can still hear sounds from a video game whose task is reduced (back to Windows desktop)

Tags: windows, windows-10

For no apparent reason, I can now hear the sounds of applications (like video games) that I reduce to taskbar in order to temporarily go back to desktop. It's incredibly annoying and it's the very first time I have this problem.

Any suggestion as to why this occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you asknig the reason you can still hear sounds from a minmized application?  If you are then the application was programmed to support that activity. There might be an option to mute audio if the process is minimzed, if there isn't an option, you will have to manually mute the application's sounds before you mimized it.

Comment: That's what I thought initially (that it came from one particular game). Then I realized the same issue was now happening with (almost) all games so it's definitely Windows-related not related to these particular applications.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1438597/how-do-i-make-windows-mute-background-applications gives https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming/releases as a solution. But the muting must be done manually so it really doesn't help much.